# Segmentation Fault (core dumped) when creating multiple matrixes

Tags: c++, canny-operator

For my computer vision class, we're currently working on the Canny Edge Detection Algorithm. For those familiar, the algorithm involves using the greyscale of an image to create the gradient vector for each pixel. Thus my code has two matrixes for storing this information, one of the magnitudes and one of the angles.

```
double edge[height][width];
double max = 0;
for(int r = 0; r<height; r++)
{
    for(int c = 0; c<width; c++)
    {
        if(r==0||c==0||r+1==height||c+1==width)
        {
            edge[r][c]=0;
        }
        else
        {
            edge[r][c]=sqrt(pow((2*greyscale[r-1][c])+greyscale[r-1][c+1]+greyscale[r-1][c-1]-(2*greyscale[r+1][c])-greyscale[r+1][c+1]-greyscale[r+1][c-1],2.0)+pow((2*greyscale[r][c-1])+greyscale[r+1][c-1]+greyscale[r-1][c-1]-(2*greyscale[r][c+1])-greyscale[r-1][c+1]-greyscale[r+1][c+1],2.0));
            if(edge[r][c]>max)
            {
                max=edge[r][c];
            }
        }
    }
}
//cout<<"makes edge"<<endl;
double atans[height][width]; //should work, but creates memory error when uncommented
for(int r = 0; r<height; r++)
{
    for(int c = 0; c<width; c++)
    {
        cout<<r<<", "<<c<<endl;
        if(r==0||c==0||r+1==height||c+1==width)
        {
            atans[r][c]=0;
        }
        else
        {
            atans[r][c] = atan2(2*greyscale[r-1][c]+greyscale[r-1][c+1]+greyscale[r-1][c-1]-2*greyscale[r+1][c]-greyscale[r+1][c+1]-greyscale[r+1][c-1],2*greyscale[r][c-1]+greyscale[r+1][c-1]+greyscale[r-1][c-1]-2*greyscale[r][c+1]-greyscale[r-1][c+1]-greyscale[r+1][c+1]);
        }
    }
}
```

My code makes the edge matrix fine, but will give me a segmentation fault when I attempt to make the atan matrix.
Any suggestions on how to fix this?

Comment: Unless `height` and `width` are compile time constants this is a non standard VLA.  Remember that the stack is usually limited to 10MB on linux and 1 MB on windows.

Comment: `double edge[height][width];` -- We need to see exactly what `height` and `width` are declared as.  As mentioned, if `height` and `width` are not constants, that line is not valid C++.

Comment: What are the dimensions of `greyscale`matrix ? Should be larger than `[height][width]`

Comment: OT: Consider using [`std::hypot(x, y);`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/math/hypot) instead of `sqrt(pow(x, 2.0) + pow(y, 2.0));`

Answer (score 2):

I assume you defined `greyscale[height][width]`.

Then, in the line

```
atans[r][c] =   
atan2(2*greyscale[r-1][c]+greyscale[r-1][c+1]+greyscale[r-1][c-1]-2*greyscale[r+1][c]-greyscale[r+1][c+1]
-greyscale[r+1][c-1],2*greyscale[r][c-1]+greyscale[r+1][c-1]+greyscale[r-1][c-1]-2*greyscale[r][c+1]
-greyscale[r-1][c+1]-greyscale[r+1][c+1]);
```

You get out of bound.

The condition :

```
  r+1==height||c+1==width
```

is not enough.

The test should be with `height-1` and  `width-1`

Comment: @user463035818 Thank you. I modified my answer to be more accurate

Answer (score 1):

The most likely problem is an access to the array out of bounds. There are tools like `valgrind` that can detect this with no code changes. Other possibilities include stepping through the code with a debugger or adding `assert`s before all accesses to the array.

Another possibility is to switch from using a plain array to using a `std::vector` of `std::vector`s or some other C++ collection that can easily support bounds checking.

The other possibility is that `height` and `width` are just very large, such that the array requires accessing more memory than your platform can access on the stack. Switching to dynamic allocation or something that can produce an error if memory is insufficient rather than crashing would be a good idea. You can also start by logging them to see if this is a likely problem.

I'd suggest not allocating such arrays on the stack because different platforms have different stack size limitations. So this makes your code fragile even if it does work.

Answer (score 1):

Allocate your array in a vector, preferably 1D vector.

The issue is that this line:

```
double atans[height][width];
```

if you are using variable `height` and `width`, then this is not valid C++, as this is C99.

If they are constant, then it's valid C++, but you are allocating your array on the stack and may be blowing it up.